# Sending javafx rectangle/pane through socket

Tags: java, sockets, javafx

I'm developing a little game multi-player using javafx. I have an object Map, which extends the class AnchorPane. This map contain some "Tiles" which extends the class Rectangle.
The classes Map and Tile implements Serializable.

What I want :

The server create the map, but don't show it. Every time a player connects, the map is sended.

Thing is that my I display the map after received it (client side), it show nothing... Every tiles is in the map, but it doesn't show.

Question 1 : AnchorPane and Rectangle doesn't implement Serializable, is it why the map doesn't display anything ? Even if I use "custom" object which implement Serializable ?

Question 2 : More generally, is it a good way to implement multi-player side ? I mean, is it "better" to have a Server with a MapController sending the map after each actions, or is it better that each client have it's own map, and the server send commands which are executed by the client ? (like create new player, move player....)

Comment: A general rule: don't send "view" (GUI) objects over sockets as this is unnecessary and inefficient. Instead send data that represents the state of models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not really possible to answer, due to the lack of code in the question, but any object that is serializable will serialize aggregated objects. If those objects are not from classes implementing serializable, you will get an exception. You should see the exception somewhere, unless you are squashing them (i.e. `try { /* code */ } catch (IOException exc) { /* do nothing */}`), which is very bad practice.
2. You should send *data* over the stream, not your view of the data. So you should have a "model" class just representing the data you need; you can easily make that serializable if you want to use object serialization as your communication protocol. Keep the view classes (i.e. the UI classes) on the client side, and update them with data from the model when you receive it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Actually the fact that I should send data instead of view bypass my first issue.